# How to create a 3D bar chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to recreate the image below. It's supposed to be a 3D bar chart, I will have to feed it dynamic data and make sure the bars rise to the correct percentages. Forget about the shadings I can use solid colors but my hope is to be able to show animated transitions as the chart values change. As you can see the bars are lined up vertically and have an angle to them, there will be a div with content on its left side.

I don't know where to start! What would be a good approach to this project? I heard some good things about D3.js but I'm wondering if there's a simpler CSS3 approach I can take. Any ideas?

[image: 3D Bar Chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this with javascript and the canvas tag, but if you don't want to use D3.js, which is an excellent graphing library, then you may want to look at WebGL, or emulate 3D in canvas.

You could also look at http://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-column-chart/, which provides a free library.

For an interesting article to help you, you can read this:  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-animated-3d-bar-chartgraph--net-24831

For css you can look at this:
http://codepen.io/TimRuby/pen/ysfGe

```
<h1>Transparent CSS Only Bar Graph</h1>
  <div class="chart-container">
    <div class="base"></div>
        <!-- Left Side Meter-->
    <ul class="meter">
      <li><div>$100,000</div></li>
      <li><div>$80,000</div></li>
      <li><div>$60,000</div></li>
      <li><div>$40,000</div></li>
      <li><div>Less Than $20,000</div></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Background-Grid -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Background Grid -->

    <div class="bar one"></div>   
    <div class="bar two"></div>   
    <div class="bar three"></div>
    <div class="bar four"></div>   
    <div class="bar five"></div>   
    <div class="bar six"></div>
    <div class="bar seven"></div>   
    <div class="bar eight"></div> 
  </div>

html, body {
  background-color: #222;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

h1 {
  margin: 60px auto 0;
  width: 550px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.base {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -35px;
  width: 825px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
}

.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  /*border: solid 1px #bbb;*/
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.055);
/*  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #444;
*/}

.chart-container:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -8px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.055);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

.chart-container > table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chart-container table  tr  td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 98x;
  border: solid 1px  rgba(255,255,255,0.05);

}

.meter {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: -30px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(20,113,163,0.5);
  border-left: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

}

.meter:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -15px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(14,81,117,0.9);
   -moz-transform: skewY(45deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform: skewY(45deg);
}

.meter:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(13,171,217,0.45);
   -moz-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}

.meter li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 99px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #0DABD9;
}

.meter li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #0DABD9;
  -moz-transform: skewY(45deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform: skewY(45deg);
}

.meter li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.meter li:last-child:before {
  border: 0;
}

.meter li div {
  position: absolute;
  left: -115px;
  top: 0;
  padding: 55px 0 0;
  width: 80px;
  color: #656565;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* ---------------------
  Vertical Bars
----------------------*/

.bar {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 35%;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 40px;
  background-color: rgba(107,255,49,0.35);
}

.bar:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: 7px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(107,255,49,0.25);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
}

.bar:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -8px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(107,255,49,0.45);
  -moz-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}

.two {
  left: 12.5%;
  height: 57%;
}

.three {
  left: 25%;
  height: 85%;
}

.four {
  left: 37.5%;
  height: 35%;
}

.five {
  left: 50%;
  height: 63%;
}

.six {
  left: 62.5%;
  height: 45%;
}

.seven {
  left: 75%;
  height: 15%;
}

.eight {
  left: 87.5%;
  height: 32%;
}
```

If you can show some code then it would be easier to help you determine what you need to do to get the graph you want.

Edit: A working 3D example is available [here](https://bl.ocks.org/niekes/613d43d39372f99ae2dcea14f0f90617)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a 3D bar chart using d3 and x3dom http://bl.ocks.org/camio/5087116

It can at least get you started.